# leetcode 56 : using java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
    class Solution {
    public int[][] merge(int[][] intervals) {
        ArrayList<Integer>list=new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Integer>tem=new ArrayList();
        List<List<Integer>>2d_ans=new ArrayList<>();
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<intervals.length;i++){
            if(list.get(1)==0){
                list.add(intervals[i][0]);
                list.add(intervals[i][1]);
            }
            else if(list.get(1)>=interval[i][0]){
                //int temp=j++;
                tem.add(list.get(0));
                tem.add(interval[i][1]);
                2d_ans.add(tem);
                tem.clear();
                list.clear();
                list.add(intervals[i][0]);
                list.add(intervals[i][1]);
            }
            else{
                list.clear();
                list.add(intervals[i][0]);
                list.add(intervals[i][1]);
                2d_ans.add(list);
            }
        }
        //Collections.sort(list);
        return 2d_ans;
    }
}
```

I am trying to solve leetcode 56th problem but i'm getting an not a statement error at line 5 can someone help. Link to the problem is given below.

https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-intervals/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have issues:

- Java variable names can't start with numbers.
- ans_2d is declared as a list of lists; you have to load it into an array of arrays OR change the return type.

> ```
> import java.util.ArrayList;
> import java.util.List;
>
> class Solution {
>     public List<List<Integer>> merge(int[][] intervals) {
>         ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
>         ArrayList<Integer>tem=new ArrayList<>();
>         List<List<Integer>> ans_2d =new ArrayList<>();
>         int count=0;
>         for(int i=0;i<intervals.length;i++){
>             if(list.get(1)==0){
>                 list.add(intervals[i][0]);
>                 list.add(intervals[i][1]);
>             }
>             else if(list.get(1)>=intervals[i][0]){
>                 //int temp=j++;
>                 tem.add(list.get(0));
>                 tem.add(intervals[i][1]);
>                 ans_2d.add(tem);
>                 tem.clear();
>                 list.clear();
>                 list.add(intervals[i][0]);
>                 list.add(intervals[i][1]);
>             }
>             else{
>                 list.clear();
>                 list.add(intervals[i][0]);
>                 list.add(intervals[i][1]);
>                 ans_2d.add(list);
>             }
>         }
>         //Collections.sort(list);
>         return ans_2d;
>     }
> }
> ```

I didn't read your problem or check your code to see if it solves it.  The compiler is happy now.